# Mongoose apply getters before find

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have inherited a Mongo collection that stores Dates as strings e.g. "2020-11-18" rather than as BSON Dates. I have a getter that converts this string to a js Date but I would like to query the collection by date range as follows:

```
const Things = mongoose.Model('Thing',
    {
        date: { type: String, get v => new Date(v) }
    }, 
    {
        toJSON: { getters: true },
        toObject: { getters: true },
    }
)

Things.find({ date: { $gt: new Date("2020-11-17"), $lt: new Date("2020-11-19") } })
```

It seems that the getter is not applied to documents before the find query is executed. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates in that format have the fortunate property that their lexicographic sort order is the same as their chronological order.

That means that you can query them as strings and match the documents you would expect.

For example, in a collection containing

```
[
    {"date": "2020-11-16"},
    {"date": "2020-11-17"},
    {"date": "2020-11-18"},
    {"date": "2020-11-19"}
]
```

The query

```
db.Things.find({"date": {$gte: "2020-11-17", $lt: "2020-11-19"}})
```

Returns  `{"date": "2020-11-17"}` and `{"date": "2020-11-18"}`, as expected.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hii273DoPnq)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in this [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/getters-setters.html):

> Getters allow you to transform the **representation** of the data as it
> travels from the raw mongodb document to the value that you see.

So your `date` getter will run just after the execution of the **find()** method. Otherwise, how the date's representation will be changed before finding the date itself !

In another words:

```
Things.find({ date: { $gt: new Date("2020-11-17"), $lt: new Date("2020-11-19") } })
    // getter will run here
    .then((queryResults) =>{
      
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Is there a way then to transform the data before the find is issued?

Comment: You are welcome. 
( Is there a way then to transform the data before the find is issued? ) can you explaine more what you need please ...